# Subset dataframe based on a specific number of unique values in a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, split, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe:

```
group_eg <- data.frame(
  CID = c(091, 091, 091, 091,
          101, 101, 101,
          102, 102, 102, 
          103, 103,
          104, 104, 104),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1091, 1091,
            1101, 1101, 1101,
            1102, 1102, 1102,
            1103, 1103,
            1104, 1104, 1104),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2091, 2091, 2091,
            2101, 2101, 2101, 
            2102, 2102, 2102,
            2103, 2103,
            2104, 2104, 2104),
  text = c("eg1", "eg2", "eg3", "eg3", 
           "eg4","eg5", "eg6", 
           "eg7", "eg8","eg9", 
           "eg10", "eg11", 
           "eg12", "eg13", "eg14")
)
```

I want to divide this dataframe into a list of smaller dataframes. Each of the smaller dataframes should only contain rows that belong to 2 unique CIDs in ascending order. If the number of CIDs is not divisible by 2, the last dataframe can contain the rows that belong to just 1 CID. Notice that there are different number of observations for each unique CID, so I'm a bit stuck.

Here are the example outputs:

```
output1 <- data.frame(
  CID = c(091, 091, 091, 091,
          101, 101, 101),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1091, 1091,
            1101, 1101, 1101),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2091, 2091, 2091,
            2101, 2101, 2101),
  text = c("eg1", "eg2", "eg3", "eg3", 
           "eg4","eg5", "eg6")
)

output2 <- data.frame(
  CID = c(102, 102, 102, 
          103, 103),
  PID_A = c(1102, 1102, 1102,
            1103, 1103),
  PID_B = c(2102, 2102, 2102,
            2103, 2103),
  text = c( "eg7", "eg8","eg9", 
           "eg10", "eg11")
)

output3 <- data.frame(
  CID = c(104, 104, 104),
  PID_A = c(1104, 1104, 1104),
  PID_B = c(2104, 2104, 2104),
  text = c("eg12", "eg13", "eg14")
)
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr::consecutive_id` and integer division `%/%` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

group_eg |>
  group_by(group = (consecutive_id(CID) + 1) %/% 2) |>
  group_split()
#> <list_of<
#>   tbl_df<
#>     CID  : double
#>     PID_A: double
#>     PID_B: double
#>     text : character
#>     group: double
#>   >
#> >[3]>
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>     CID PID_A PID_B text  group
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1    91  1091  2091 eg1       1
#> 2    91  1091  2091 eg2       1
#> 3    91  1091  2091 eg3       1
#> 4    91  1091  2091 eg3       1
#> 5   101  1101  2101 eg4       1
#> 6   101  1101  2101 eg5       1
#> 7   101  1101  2101 eg6       1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>     CID PID_A PID_B text  group
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1   102  1102  2102 eg7       2
#> 2   102  1102  2102 eg8       2
#> 3   102  1102  2102 eg9       2
#> 4   103  1103  2103 eg10      2
#> 5   103  1103  2103 eg11      2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>     CID PID_A PID_B text  group
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1   104  1104  2104 eg12      3
#> 2   104  1104  2104 eg13      3
#> 3   104  1104  2104 eg14      3
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help from `data.table::rleid`, you can do a `split`, which gives a list of three dataframes.

```r
library(data.table)

group_eg_split <- split(group_eg, paste0("output_", ceiling(rleid(group_eg$CID)/2)))

group_eg_split 
$output_1
  CID PID_A PID_B text
1  91  1091  2091  eg1
2  91  1091  2091  eg2
3  91  1091  2091  eg3
4  91  1091  2091  eg3
5 101  1101  2101  eg4
6 101  1101  2101  eg5
7 101  1101  2101  eg6

$output_2
   CID PID_A PID_B text
8  102  1102  2102  eg7
9  102  1102  2102  eg8
10 102  1102  2102  eg9
11 103  1103  2103 eg10
12 103  1103  2103 eg11

$output_3
   CID PID_A PID_B text
13 104  1104  2104 eg12
14 104  1104  2104 eg13
15 104  1104  2104 eg14
```

To assign the list elements into individual objects, use `list2env`. After this, three objects with name "output_1" to "output_3" will be generated in your environment.

```r
list2env(group_eg_split, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: thanks @benson23 ! is there a command to save the output dataframes in the list into separate CSVs?

Comment: @jo_ You can use `lapply` to iterate over the list and use `write.csv` in the function.

Answer (score 2):

with base R:

```
CID_uniq <- as.character(unique(group_eg$CID))
hash <- ceiling(setNames(seq_along(CID_uniq), CID_uniq) / 2)

list_of_dataframes <- 
  split(group_eg,
        f = hash[as.character(group_eg$CID)]
        )
```

```
## > str(list_of_dataframes)
## List of 3
##  $ 1:'data.frame':   7 obs. of  4 variables:
##   ..$ CID  : num [1:7] 91 91 91 91 101 101 101
##   ..$ PID_A: num [1:7] 1091 1091 1091 1091 1101 ...
##   ..$ PID_B: num [1:7] 2091 2091 2091 2091 2101 ...
##   ..$ text : chr [1:7] "eg1" "eg2" "eg3" "eg3" ...
##  $ 2:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
##   ..$ CID  : num [1:5] 102 102 102 103 103
##   ..$ PID_A: num [1:5] 1102 1102 1102 1103 1103
##   ..$ PID_B: num [1:5] 2102 2102 2102 2103 2103
##   ..$ text : chr [1:5] "eg7" "eg8" "eg9" "eg10" ...
##  $ 3:'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
##   ..$ CID  : num [1:3] 104 104 104
##   ..$ PID_A: num [1:3] 1104 1104 1104
##   ..$ PID_B: num [1:3] 2104 2104 2104
##   ..$ text : chr [1:3] "eg12" "eg13" "eg14"
```